# Add strings to an array

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, c-strings, strcpy

The problem: After the  *convert_tolower(words)* function is completed I want to add a new word in the *words* array( if the words array has less than 5 words)..But I am getting either errors or unexpected results(e.g some weird characters being printed)...What i thought is shifting the elements of the *words* array and then work with pointers because I am dealing with strings.But I am having quite some trouble achieving that..Probably the problem is in lines
35-37

How I want the program to behave:

1. Get 5 words(strings) at most from user input
2. Take these strings and place them in an array *words*
3. Convert the elements of the array to lowercase letters
4. After the above,ask the user again to enter a new word and pick the position of that word.If the *words* array already has 5 words then the new word is not added.Else,the new word is added in the position the user chose.(The other words are not deleted,they are just 'shifted').

Also by *words[1]* I refer to the first word of the *words* array in its entirety

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define W 5
#define N 10

void convert_tolower(char matrix[W][N]);

int main() {
  int j = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int len = 0;
  char words[W][N] = {{}};
  char test[W][N];
  char endword[N] = "end";
  char newword[N];
  int position;
  while (scanf("%9s", test), strcmp(test, endword)) {
    strcpy(words[i++], test);

    j++;
    len++;
    if (j == W) {
      break;
    }
  }

  convert_tolower(words);

  printf("Add a new word\n");
  scanf("%9s", newword);
  printf("\nPick the position\n");
  scanf("%d",position);
  if (len < W) {
    for (i = 0; i < W-1; i++) {
      strcpy(words[i], words[i + 1]); /*Shift the words */
      words[position] = newword;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < W; i++) {
    printf("%s", words[i]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  printf("End of program");
  return 0;
}

void convert_tolower(char matrix[W][N]) {
  int i;
  int j;
  for (i = 0; i < W; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      matrix[i][j] = tolower(matrix[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In addition to describing the problem please also define the intended behaviour of your program.

Comment: Please add the part of your [mre] where you init the pointers in `words` so that they point to memory which you are allowed to write to. I can't find it in the shown code.

Comment: Your use of the pointers in `words` is strange. You define `words` as 2D, but use it as 1D. I seem to be missing something. Please describe your understanding of what `words` is. What data type does the 2D array contain? What datatype do you access in the 1D array? If pointers are involved please describe what they are pointing to  and why you think you can write there. If "strings" are used, please discuss maximum lenghts and/or termination.

Comment: I am not that sure I have to work with pointers though..

Comment: Then please reconsider your decision to define a 2D array of pointers.

Comment: You are right..I think I must use strcpy in such a way to get what I want..But this is the problem...

Comment: Why are you using a 2d array of char * for words? Either use a 1d array of char *, or a 2d array of char.

Comment: Eh..What do you  mean by that?

Comment: You represent a word with a `char *` or `char[N]`.  An array of words would be `char *[W]`  or `char [N][W]` (or reversed indexes).  So why do you want words to be and 2d array of pointers?  It looks like you changed it so you probably figured it out already.

Comment: Right..But I need to correct lines 35-37...

Comment: Please explain in more detail how step 4 works.  If you read in 0 word can you insert in pos 1 through 4 (i.e. are blank words allowed)?

Comment: Which one of all the errors in your code do you want help with?

Comment: @Alan Wind the exercise does not really clarify if blank words are allowed.Also I added a bit more details in step 4

Comment: @August Karlstorm lines 34-37 is the main problem(I think)

Comment: regarding: `char endword[N] = "end";`  in C, arrays are indexed from 0 to (number of  elements in array -1)   So this statement results in `end` being inserted immediately after the end of the array.  This results in undefined behavior.  Since `N` is 10, the valid indexes are 0...9

Answer (score 4):

This initialization

```
char words[W][N] = {{}};
```

is incorrect in C. If you want to zero initialize the array then just write for example

```
char words[W][N] = { 0 };
```

In the condition of the while loop

```
while (scanf("%9s", test), strcmp(test, endword)) {
```

there is used the comma operator. Moreover you are using incorrectly the two-dimensional array `test` instead of a one-dimensional array

It seems you mean

```
char test[N];

//...

while ( scanf("%9s", test) == 1 && strcmp(test, endword) != 0 ) {
```

And there are used redundantly too many variables like `i`, `j` and `len`.

The loop could be written simpler like

```
char test[N];

//...

for ( ; len < W && scanf("%9s", test) == 1 && strcmp(test, endword) != 0; ++len ) 
{
    strcpy(words[len], test);
}
```

In this call

```
scanf("%d",position);
```

there is a typo. You must to write

```
scanf("%d", &position);
```

Also you should check whether the entered value of `position`  is in the range `[0, len]`.

For example

```
position = -1;

printf("\nPick the position\n");
scanf("%d", &position); 

if ( len < W && -1 < position && position <= len ) {
```

Also this for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < W-1; i++) {
  strcpy(words[i], words[i + 1]); /*Shift the words */
  words[position] = newword;
}
```

does not make a sense. And moreover this assignment statement

```
  words[position] = newword;
```

is invalid. Arrays do not have the assignment operator.

You need to move all strings starting from the specified position to the right.
For example

```
for ( i = len; i != position; --i )
{
    strcpy( words[i], words[i-1] );
}

strcpy( words[position], newword );
++len;
```

And it seems the function `convert_tolower` should be called for the result array after inserting a new word. And moreover you need to pass the number of actual words in the array.

```
convert_tolower(words, len);
```

The nested loops within the function convert_tolower should look at least the following way

```
void convert_tolower(char matrix[][N], int n) {
  int i;
  int j;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; matrix[i][j] != '\0'; j++) {
      matrix[i][j] = tolower(( unsigned char )matrix[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That must have taken you a long time.  You have more patience than me :-)

Comment: Just one small remark: `-1 < position` is more risky than `0 <= position` which would still work if the type of `position` was changed to `size_t`. Also why not test the return value of `scanf()` in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your code was initially that you declared `char *words[W][N]`, then tried to `insert` strings into this 2d array of pointers. Sparse use of organizing functions, and variables with large scopes than necessary made it hard to read.  I think the best way to help you is to show you a working minimal implementation.  Step 4 is not sufficiently specified.  `insert` currently shift.  It is not clear what should happen if you insert at position after empty slots, or if insert a position before empty slots and in particular if there are non-empty slots after said position.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define W 5
#define N 10

void convert(size_t w, size_t n, char list[][n]) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < w; i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            list[i][j] = tolower(list[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void insert(size_t w, size_t n, char list[][n], size_t pos, char *word) {
    // out out of bounds
    if(pos + 1 > w) return;

    // shift pos through w - 2 pos
    for(size_t i = w - 2; i >= pos; i--) {
        strcpy(list[i + 1], list[i]);
        if(!i) break;
    }
    // insert word at pos
    strcpy(list[pos], word);
}

void print(size_t w, size_t n, char list[][n]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < w; i++) {
        printf("%u: %s\n", i, list[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    char words[W][N] = { "a", "BB", "c" };
    convert(W, N, words);
    insert(W, N, words, 0, "start");
    insert(W, N, words, 2, "mid");
    insert(W, N, words, 4, "end");
    insert(W, N, words, 5, "error")
    print(W, N, words);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output (note: "c" was shifted out as we initially had 3 elements and added 3 new words with valid positions):

```
0: start
1: a
2: mid
3: bb
4: end
```

Comment: Why is size_t needed in every for loop?

Comment: It's just a convenient unsigned type.  If you use `int` then you allow for negative indices which is a source of errors.  I use a local loop variable to minimize their scope.

Comment: Using `size_t` is consistent but then change `printf("%d: %s\n", i, list[i]);` to `printf("%zu: %s\n", i, list[i]);`